# Toshiba Strata CIX Calls From 'cisco'

Tags: voip

We have a Toshiba Strata VOIP phone system. Getting bombarded with calls from 'cisco'. Answering the call immediately hangs up. Happening every 3-4 seconds. Not sure if they are originating from outside our office or if it is an internal thing. I do not have a device on our lan title 'cisco', so I'm not sure where its coming from.

Any ideas how to stop this before our receptionist quits?

Comment: There isn't [enough detail](http://tinyurl.com/ne-checklist) for us to know, but a complete shot in the dark is that someone enabled a SIP monitor of your Toshiba's call reception function.  You should sniff the traffic to the Toshiba and track down the source ip address making the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calls were coming from an "unknown source" via our VOIP service provider. They have since blocked the calls and everything is as normal.